# How can I check the value of 'this' with a Jasmine spy?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocking, jasmine

I want to verify that a Jasmine spy is invoked with a certain object for `this`. How can I do this?

A contrived example:

```
var spy = jasmine.createSpy('method');
var obj = {property: 'value'};
spy.apply(obj);
// How can we verify that 'this' in the call to spy is 'obj'?​​​​​​​​
```

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/2eRQG/) for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I couldn't find any documentation on this feature (sorry if I missed something), the value of `this` is recorded for each call to a spy.

```
var spy = jasmine.createSpy('method');
var obj = {
    property: 'value'
};
spy.apply(obj);
expect(spy.mostRecentCall.object).toEqual(obj);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aknuds1/wDHHP/) for a demo.

Comment: This is now part of the public API in 2.2.  http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-30     

expect(foo.setBar.calls.first()).toEqual({object: foo, args: [123], returnValue: undefined});

Answer (score 0):

I met such problem when working on tests, so I decided to wrote custom spy matchers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spy-matchers

Using them you can access a new matcher:

```js
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWithContext(obj)

//or

expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWithContext(obj, 'foo', 'bar')
```

It works the same way like toHaveBeenCalledWith but can validate `context` also